# Concatening LIKE with Stored Procedure's parameter using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

### The goal

Concatenate a parameter with a `%` operator of LIKE using MySQL.

### The problem

There's the following query on my database and it returns me the results very well:

```
SELECT people.LOGIN, people.EMAIL FROM people
WHERE people.LOGIN LIKE 'o%'
ORDER BY people.LOGIN ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

But I want to call this function using a Stored Procedure, and instead of use `'o%'`, I want to use `'<myvariable>%'` and I'm not managing to do this.

### The scenario

I've tried the following on my procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT people.EMAIL FROM people
    WHERE people.LOGIN LIKE CONCAT(expression, '%')
    ORDER BY people.LOGIN ASC
    LIMIT 10;
END
```

The result? **Empty.** This query returns me nothing.

**Someone has any idea to help me?**

Comment: Is the second query your actual query? the CONCAT(expression, '%') part - what is expression?

Comment: The second query is my stored procedure. They are the same thing, but one is applied to a Stored Procedure and the other is a "plug and play" query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often what actually gets passed in is not what we think.

Check that the parameter:

- is not null
- does not have leading or trailing whitespace

Try this to guard against the above:

```
WHERE people.LOGIN LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(IFNULL(expression, '')), '%')
```

Comment: There's not whitespaces, it's a valid string but still returning me zero results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Create a string with a query, and execute it using prepared statements. Something like this -

```
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE ''', expression, '%''');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I did not know about **prepared statements** — thanks for introducing to me this amazing feature. More knowledge to me. I used your solution and touché! Worked like a charm! Thanks! +1

Comment: Check the `expression` argument, if it is NULL, then result @query will be NULL too.

Comment: You do not "need" to use prepared statements and concatenating queries together like this can set you up for substantial security risks; `LIKE CONCAT(variable,'%')` works fine in the original query and the value in the variable does not need to be sanitized in that case.  Your original problem was most likely due to the variable not containing what you thought.

Comment: I think @Bohemian already has captured what I was thinking, that essentially the problem is likely to be what's in the variable rather than the way the query was being constructed; I just wanted to add the usual danger warning about mixing external data into queries when, in this case, it can be avoided.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did what you said, but even having a value within the parameter, the result is zero. Only if I use the letter `a` as parameter the query returns me a result. To be more specific, a single result. I can't understand what's happening: I'm filling the SP's parameter with letters behaved by apostrophes and the result is always zero. If I set up a number without the apostrophes, then I get the right results. What can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LOCATE. Example:

WHERE LOCATE(pParamText, column1) > 0